# Problema al enviar datos desde Javascript en un div

Tags: php, javascript, materialize

Buenas estoy usando Materialize CSS 1.0.0 y me funciona muy bien a excepción de cuando quiero enviarle HTML desde Javascript. La pagina `informe.php` tiene un div y uso `informe.js` para enviarle el código, según distintos usuarios. Tengo distintos botones que llaman distintas funciones en la cabecera.

```js
function horasAct(){
    //Carga cabecera de Horas
    cadena="cabecera=Horas";
    
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"../content/informes/btnHoras.php",
        data:cadena,
        success:function(result){
            $('#divBotones').html(result);
        }
    });

    // Tomar nuevos elementos y aplicar DatePicker
    let DatePi = document.querySelectorAll('#fechaIni .datepiicker');
    let instancesDP = M.Datepicker.init(DatePi);
    let DatePe = document.querySelectorAll('#fechaEnd .datepicker');
    let instancesDP = M.Datepicker.init(DatePe);
    let sel = document.querySelectorAll('#userSel select');
    let instancesSel = M.FormSelect.init(sel);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- LLamada a la funcion horasACt() -->
<button class="waves-effect waves-light btn indigo" onclick="horasAct()">
                <i class="material-icons">access_alarm</i>
        Horas
            </button>

<-- div que recibe el código HTML -->
<div class="row">
            <div id="divBotones"></div><!-- Línea de Menú -->
</div>

</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        //Sidenav menu
        var sideN = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
        var instancesSN = M.Sidenav.init(sideN);
        // ventana modal
        var mod = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
        var instancesMod = M.Modal.init(mod);
        //Collapsive
        var collap = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
        var instancesColl = M.Collapsible.init(collap);
        //DatePicker
        var DateP = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
        var instancesDP = M.Datepicker.init(DateP);
    });
  </script>
```

Archivo al que llama el Ajax de la función horosAct() donde recorre una tabla de usuarios para llenar un select. En este caso he quitado el bucle, para poder comprobar el código sin tener que modificar tanto.

```php
<?php
session_start();
require_once "../compo/conexion.php";
$conexion=conexion();
$sql="SELECT id,usuario from cmd_user  ORDER BY usuario ASC";
$result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

$cadena= "<div class='col s12'>
            <div class='card small blue lighten-5 '>
                <div class=card-content white-text'>
                        <span class='card-title'>Horas</span>
                        
                        <div class='col s6 m4'>
                            <input id='fechaIni' type='text' class='datepicker'>
                            <label for='fechaIni'>Desde</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col s6 m4'>
                            <input id='fechaEnd' type='text' class='datepicker'>
                            <label for='fechaEnd'>Hasta</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class='input-field col s6 m4'>
                        <select id='userSel'>
                            <option value='0' selected>Todos</option>
                            <option value='1'>Uno</option>
                            <option value='2'>Dos</option>
                            </select>
                        <label>Usuario</label>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class='card-action'>
                    <a href='#'>Buscar</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>";
echo $cadena;
?>
```

la intención es tener una sección de informes, con una cabecera de botones que mostrarían diferentes informes dinámicamente, con una tarjeta para realizar filtros y luego mostrar detalles abajo, según el tipo de informe.

Comment: Cargando jQuery en el fragmento de código funciona correctamente. Revisa la consola del navegador para ver si encuentras algún error.

Comment: Perdona me he liado yo, que deje un picker sin materielize para ver si funcionaba, tengo que volver a editerlo para poner el codigo correcto

Comment: Ahora si, me muestra el control, pero no se despliega

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que los elementos todavía no existen cuando aplicas *DatePicker()*, dentro de la función selecciona solo los nuevos, usando el contenedor como padre y buscando los que tengan la clase `.datepicker`:

```js
function horasAct(){
cadena="<input type='text' class='datepicker'>";
    $('#divBotones').html(cadena);
    // Tomar nuevos elementos y aplicar DatePicker
    let DateP = document.querySelectorAll('#divBotones .datepicker');
    let instancesDP = M.Datepicker.init(DateP);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<!-- LLamada a la funcion horasACt() -->
<button class="waves-effect waves-light btn indigo" onclick="horasAct()">
                <i class="material-icons">access_alarm</i>
        Horas
            </button>

<-- div que recibe el código HTML -->
<div class="row">
            <div id="divBotones"></div><!-- Línea de Menú -->
</div>

</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        //Sidenav menu
        var sideN = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
        var instancesSN = M.Sidenav.init(sideN);
        // ventana modal
        var mod = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
        var instancesMod = M.Modal.init(mod);
        //Collapsive
        var collap = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
        var instancesColl = M.Collapsible.init(collap);
        //DatePicker
        var DateP = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
        var instancesDP = M.Datepicker.init(DateP);
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Genial con esto si funciona,la primera función selecciona todos los datepicker y la segunda los activa?

Comment: @Nelson, es correcto, con `querySelectorAll()` los seleccionas y con la siguiente _instrucción_ los activas como DatePicker().

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!!

Comment: Buenas @Triby, me surge otro problema, si a esta función le pongo un select, he intentado hacer lo mismo, seleccionar el select y activarlo, pero me deja de funcionar datepicker. Puedo activar elemento por elemento?

Comment: Sin ver cómo haces lo del _select_ va a ser difícil saber lo que pasa. Edita la pregunta o crea una nueva.

Comment: Ok, voy, gracias de nuevo @Triby

Comment: @Nelson, debes editar tu pregunta, no mi respuesta.

Comment: Ufff, que nooby, perdona!!!